# Access Javascript JSON object properties with XPath style

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, jsonpath

I have a Java script Object and I need to dynamically read, write and delete values based on the [`JSONPath`](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Is there a library for JavaScript?

I know that there is jsonpath.js but this is only to fetch a value or an object based on the `JSONPath`. Please help.

An example:

Suppose I have this JavaScript object

```
var someData = {
    store: {
        book: [{
            category: "fiction",
            author: "Herman Melville",
            title: "Moby Dick",
            isbn: "0-553-21311-3",
            price: 8.99
        }, {
            category: "fiction",
            author: "some Author"
            title: "The Lord of the Rings",
            isbn: "0-395-19395-8",
            price: 22.99
        }],
    }
}
```

and I have a `JSONPath = $.store.book[0].author` 
this `JSONPath` varies every time.
so this `JSONPath` points to the author named Herman Melville
lets us say the value to be replaced is "name2" how do I do it dynamically.

and the worst case comes here

If the `JSONPath = $.store.book[*].author` see that 0 is replaced by * this means that it points to all the authors in the array book.

So I should be able to read and write the author name.

jsonpath.js does the read function but not anything else.

Please comment if I am not clear.

Comment: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb

Comment: Could you post an example of what you would like this library to do?

Comment: @AaronUllal I have added an example

Comment: @kasey take a look I have added `jsonPathRead`, `jsonPathStore`, `jsonPathDelete` functions in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like https://lodash.com/docs#set

here is an example:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

lodash.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object.a[0].b.c);
```

Comment: Heads up, if you're not using requirejs, amd, webpack, etc., then lodash is usually set as `window._`, so the example would be `_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4)`

Comment: What's the point when you can just do `object.a[0].b.c = 4`?

Comment: @OrangeDog it is to avoid verboseness. Let's say we want to assign a value to a property in the object, but we are not sure if the property is already in the object?  Traditionally, we might carefully traverse down into the object something like this… `data.parsed = {};
data.parsed.appl = {};
data.parsed.appl.msg = message;` instead of this with _.set you can just do `_.set(data, 'parsed.appl.msg', message);`

Answer (score 0):

[l33teral](https://github.com/nicholascloud/l33teral) might help, but it doesn't use JSONPath. You can "probe" for paths that might exist before accessing them. Disclosure: I am the author.

Comment: looks like a copy and paste of lodash methods. Disclosure: I am a contributor.

Comment: @SitianLiu thanks for your input. _.set() and _.unset() weren't added until 2015/2016. I started my library in 2013. I did so to fill in gaps that I perceived in lodash and underscore. Any "copy and paste" is purely coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibile solution to store data in json parsed by the [JSONPath](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/d4131a1e15dc3af1e142feb902984219)
I'm using powerful javascript `eval` here:

```js
function jsonPath(obj,expr,arg){var P={resultType:arg&&arg.resultType||"VALUE",result:[],normalize:function(e){var t=[];return e.replace(/[\['](\??\(.*?\))[\]']/g,function(e,r){return"[#"+(t.push(r)-1)+"]"}).replace(/'?\.'?|\['?/g,";").replace(/;;;|;;/g,";..;").replace(/;$|'?\]|'$/g,"").replace(/#([0-9]+)/g,function(e,r){return t[r]})},asPath:function(e){for(var t=e.split(";"),r="$",a=1,n=t.length;n>a;a++)r+=/^[0-9*]+$/.test(t[a])?"["+t[a]+"]":"['"+t[a]+"']";return r},store:function(e,t){return e&&(P.result[P.result.length]="PATH"==P.resultType?P.asPath(e):t),!!e},trace:function(e,t,r){if(e){var a=e.split(";"),n=a.shift();if(a=a.join(";"),t&&t.hasOwnProperty(n))P.trace(a,t[n],r+";"+n);else if("*"===n)P.walk(n,a,t,r,function(e,t,r,a,n){P.trace(e+";"+r,a,n)});else if(".."===n)P.trace(a,t,r),P.walk(n,a,t,r,function(e,t,r,a,n){"object"==typeof a[e]&&P.trace("..;"+r,a[e],n+";"+e)});else if(/,/.test(n))for(var l=n.split(/'?,'?/),s=0,c=l.length;c>s;s++)P.trace(l[s]+";"+a,t,r);else/^\(.*?\)$/.test(n)?P.trace(P.eval(n,t,r.substr(r.lastIndexOf(";")+1))+";"+a,t,r):/^\?\(.*?\)$/.test(n)?P.walk(n,a,t,r,function(e,t,r,a,n){P.eval(t.replace(/^\?\((.*?)\)$/,"$1"),a[e],e)&&P.trace(e+";"+r,a,n)}):/^(-?[0-9]*):(-?[0-9]*):?([0-9]*)$/.test(n)&&P.slice(n,a,t,r)}else P.store(r,t)},walk:function(e,t,r,a,n){if(r instanceof Array)for(var l=0,s=r.length;s>l;l++)l in r&&n(l,e,t,r,a);else if("object"==typeof r)for(var c in r)r.hasOwnProperty(c)&&n(c,e,t,r,a)},slice:function(e,t,r,a){if(r instanceof Array){var n=r.length,l=0,s=n,c=1;e.replace(/^(-?[0-9]*):(-?[0-9]*):?(-?[0-9]*)$/g,function(e,t,r,a){l=parseInt(t||l),s=parseInt(r||s),c=parseInt(a||c)}),l=0>l?Math.max(0,l+n):Math.min(n,l),s=0>s?Math.max(0,s+n):Math.min(n,s);for(var o=l;s>o;o+=c)P.trace(o+";"+t,r,a)}},eval:function(x,_v,_vname){try{return $&&_v&&eval(x.replace(/@/g,"_v"))}catch(e){throw new SyntaxError("jsonPath: "+e.message+": "+x.replace(/@/g,"_v").replace(/\^/g,"_a"))}}},$=obj;return expr&&obj&&("VALUE"==P.resultType||"PATH"==P.resultType)?(P.trace(P.normalize(expr).replace(/^\$;/,""),obj,"$"),P.result.length?P.result:!1):void 0}

var console = {
  log: function(s) {
    s = s.replace(/\\n/, '<br/>');
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
  }
}

var someData = {
  store: {
    book: [{
      category: "fiction",
      author: "Herman Melville",
      title: "Moby Dick",
      isbn: "0-553-21311-3",
      price: 8.99
    }, {
      category: "fiction",
      author: "some Author",
      title: "The Lord of the Rings",
      isbn: "0-395-19395-8",
      price: 22.99
    }],
  }
}

jsonPathStore = function(obj,path,values) {
 var maps=jsonPath(obj, path,{resultType:"PATH"})
 maps.map(function(item,index) {
  return eval( '(' + item.replace(/\$/,"obj") + '="' + values[index] +'"' + ')' );
 })
}

jsonPathDelete = function(obj,path) {
 var maps=jsonPath(obj, path,{resultType:"PATH"})
 maps.map(function(item,index) {
  return eval( '(' + 'delete ' + item.replace(/\$/,"obj") + ')' );
 })
}

jsonPathRead = function(obj,path) {
 var maps=jsonPath(obj, path,{resultType:"PATH"})
 return maps.map(function(item,index) {
  return eval( '(' + item.replace(/\$/,"obj") + ')' );
 })
}

   
 console.log( "JSON "+JSON.stringify(someData, null, 2) )
 console.log( "jsonPathRead " + JSON.stringify(jsonPathRead(someData,"store.book[*].title"), null, 2) )

 jsonPathStore(someData,"store.book[*].author", ["Loreto", "Loreto Parisi"])

 console.log( "jsonPathStore " + JSON.stringify(someData, null, 2) )

 jsonPathStore(someData,"store.book[*].title", ["JavaScript", "Ninja"])

 jsonPathDelete(someData,"store.book[*].price")

 console.log( "jsonPathDelete " + JSON.stringify( eval("(" + "someData" + ")" ), null, 2) )
```

```html
<div id="console" />
```

The function `jsonPathStore` take 3 args, the json object, the xpath like string, and an array of substitutions.
The function `jsonPathDelete` takes 2 args, the json object and `xpath` like string. It will delete all matching keys.

This is a generic solution, that can improved to handle specific cases.

Comment: what are we reinventing the wheel here? There are plenty of DRY solutions out there

Comment: @SitianLiu well my answer is yes and no. There are good solutions but not `xpath` style, like JSONSelect - http://jsonselect.org, and complete different solutions to traverse a json, by the way here I'm solving a specific problem.

Comment: true true. You can totally upload this to git. I would totally star it as a Xpath specific lib.

Comment: This is a version of the same library ported to `node.js` plus editing feature - https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath based on a similar approach to edit I have showed here  - `eval` based.